# ArangoDB creating graphs that are non-empty in Java?

Tags: java, arangodb

I copied the following code from ArangoGraphTest.java:

```
private static final String GRAPH_NAME = "db_collection_test";
private static final String EDGE_COL_1 = "db_edge1_collection_test";
private static final String EDGE_COL_2 = "db_edge2_collection_test";
private static final String EDGE_COL_3 = "db_edge3_collection_test";
private static final String VERTEX_COL_1 = "db_vertex1_collection_test";
private static final String VERTEX_COL_2 = "db_vertex2_collection_test";
private static final String VERTEX_COL_3 = "db_vertex3_collection_test";
private static final String VERTEX_COL_4 = "db_vertex4_collection_test";
public static void testGraphCreate() {
    final ArangoDB arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder().user("root").password("root").build();
    final Collection<EdgeDefinition> edgeDefinitions = new ArrayList<EdgeDefinition>();
    edgeDefinitions.add(new EdgeDefinition().collection(EDGE_COL_1).from(VERTEX_COL_1).to(VERTEX_COL_2));
    edgeDefinitions
            .add(new EdgeDefinition().collection(EDGE_COL_2).from(VERTEX_COL_2).to(VERTEX_COL_1, VERTEX_COL_3));
    final GraphCreateOptions options = new GraphCreateOptions();
    ArangoDatabase db = arangoDB.db("TestArangoDB");
    db.createGraph(GRAPH_NAME, edgeDefinitions, options);

}
```

After I ran this code the expected graph db_collection_test showed up in the web interface but it says "Your graph is empty." Is this expected and if so, how can I create a non-empty graph from Java?

Answer (score 0):

This code just creates the collections in the database. There wont be any data unless you populate it. You should create all the vertices and edges as necessary.
Try creating some data with this snippet:

```
BaseDocument myObject = new BaseDocument();
myObject.setKey("myKey");
myObject.addAttribute("a", "Foo");
myObject.addAttribute("b", 42);
try {
  arangoDB.db(dbName).collection(collectionName).insertDocument(myObject);
  System.out.println("Document created");
} catch (ArangoDBException e) {
  System.err.println("Failed to create document. " + e.getMessage());
}
```